# Fatal error: Call to undefined function cache_get()

Tags: 7, caching, database

I am getting the following error on the server

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in includes/module.inc on line 665
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                [error]
Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in includes/module.inc, line 665
```

How to fix this?

Comment: In my case I found the underlying issue by adding `function cache_get() { return false; }` to `settings.php`.

Comment: In my case Ubuntu was setup to use php7 by default. Drush needs php5 assuming your server is also using php5... Try `sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php5 /etc/alternatives/php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `drush` in the command line you probably reached the right place to solve your problem. This error arises when `drush` is not up-to-date and this occurs when you install `drush` from the official repository in Ubuntu.

The workaround is easy: just install a new version of drush!
And to do so, you have to install from the backports package of Ubuntu.

Comment: I also came around same solution, I am using Drush 4.6. To which version can i upgrade?

Comment: @DineshKumarSarangapani someone downvote on this recently was that you?

Answer (score 15):

For me, the cause was different: some errors are not caught by Drupal's error handler.

I used a `new DateTime()` in my `settings.php` (probably very rare)
It generated an error because the `date.timezone` setting in my CLI `php.ini` wasn't set.

To find the real error (this is the interesting part of the answer for all of you, I think) :

Edit your `module.inc`, line 723.

Add these lines before the `cache_get` call.

```
if (!function_exists('cache_get')){ 
    debug_print_backtrace(); 
}
$implementations = cache_get('module_implements', 'cache_bootstrap');
```

It might give you lots of information about the real source of the issue!

Comment: This was very useful for me, me problem was because an issue in fast404. There seems to be several ways to reach this error, this technique will help to debug. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I had a syntax error in settings.php that resulted in Fatal error: Call to undefined function cache_get(). I'd suggest those having this issue to double check their settings.php file.

Comment: This is basically for PHP latest version issues where session.save_handler does not working. So please remove the bellow line from settings.php 
ini_set('session.save_handler',     'user');

or

Replace the line by session_set_save_handler(new SessionHandler());

----------------------------
Current line 
ini_set('session.save_handler',     'user');
Needs to Replaced by 
session_set_save_handler(new SessionHandler());

Comment: comment by @tapas was it for me. I had this issue when running drush; but only when i didn't set --uri. The default settings.php was old although i had fixed it for my multisite. When i used --uri=mymultisite; then it works. Multisite settings.php had been updated to one compatible with PHP 7